# How can I select duplicate records and keep the data using MySQL statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

For instance, my table `categories` is like this:

```
categories_id                    categories_name
----------------------         -------------------- 
1                                  aaa               
2                                  bbb               
3                                  ccc                 
5                                  ddd             
9                                  eee
```

I use the following statements to keep duplicate records. But the duplicate records do not appear.

```
SELECT categories_id, categories_name 
FROM categories
WHERE categories_name in ("aaa","bbb","bbb","ccc","ccc","ddd","ddd","ddd")
ORDER BY categories_name
```

I want to get records like this:

```
categories_id                    categories_name
----------------------         -------------------- 
1                                  aaa               
2                                  bbb
2                                  bbb               
3                                  ccc
3                                  ccc                 
5                                  ddd 
5                                  ddd            
5                                  ddd
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I really don't understand your question could you be more clear?

Comment: Just handle the logic at the application level

Comment: does the Category table contain duplicate data?

Comment: Look at his `in` statement: he's trying to list "ddd" 3 times and get back 3 "ddd" records.

Comment: What is the purpose of ("aaa","bbb","bbb","ccc","ccc","ddd","ddd","ddd")? Why not use ("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd")? The second method will clean up your query by removing redundant strings.

Comment: He wants to make duplicates that way I think. Which do not actually exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives the required output:

```
SELECT Tab1.categories_id, Tab1.categories_name
FROM categories AS Tab1
RIGHT JOIN
(
   SELECT "aaa" AS categories_name
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "bbb" 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "bbb"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "ccc"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "ccc"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "ddd"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "ddd"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "ddd"
) AS Tab2 
ON Tab1.categories_name = Tab2.categories_name
ORDER BY Tab1.categories_name;
```

An [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41c00/20).

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I create a new temp table in database and get the records.I know my application is very strange,and my english is not good,I cant express my idea very well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there would be better way of whatever you want to accomplish with the query, but for your current requirement following might be a way:

```
 SELECT c.id, a.category
 FROM 
    (SELECT 'aaa' AS category
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'aaa'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ccc'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ccc'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'eee'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'bbb'
    ) a
LEFT JOIN categories c
ON c.category = a.category
ORDER BY id;
```

See the query working at: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2897d/11